# Parse Java object to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

In Spring MVC and Jackson I have a really big Java object that I parse to a JSON string `myBigJSONString` (~1MB) and inline it into my HTML.

Then in my Javascript I do a `JSON.parse(myBigJSONString)` and everything works dandy.

However if I were to inline an syntactically correct Javascript object into my HTML and not a string representation thereof, my Javascript wouldn't have to read this huge string and parse it. It would already be parsed.

Question: How do I create a Javascript object from my Java object and inline it directly without going through a JSON string?

EDIT:

This is how my finished HTML looks right now:

```
var staticDataString = '[{\"propertyA\":\"valueA\"}, {\"propertyB\":\"valueB\"}]';
var staticData = JSON.parse(staticDataString);
```

This is how i want it to look

```
var staticData = [{propertyA:"valueA"}, {propertyB:"valueB"}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all current browsers this should work:

```
<script> 
  var obj =  <c:out value="${$myserlvetmapping.myjson}"></c:out>;
  alert(obj.test);
</script>
```

Whearat this is the Spring-Handler:

```
model.addAttribute("myjson","{test:2}");
```

Finally this would be the browsers sourcecode:

```
var obj =  {test:2};
alert(obj.test);
```

And the `alert` reports `2`.

About the creation of the JSON i suggest to use the "adapter-pattern", this means a lot of hand-written-code.

Why do you need the hand-written-adapter? Assuming you have crosswise referenced objects in java like This:

```
class Man {
  Wife wife;
}
class Wife {
  Man man;
}
Man joe = new Man();
Wife ann = new Wife();
joe.wife = ann;
ann.man = joe;
```

Your json would be

```
{man:{
  name:'joe',
  wife: {
    name: 'ann',
    man: {
      name: 'joe',
      wife: {
        name: 'ann',
        man: {
          name: 'joe',
          wife: {
            .....
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

To prevent recursion you can only use the Adapter-Pattern. This would work:

```
public final class ManJSONAdapter {
  private final Man man;
  public ManJSONAdapter(Man man){
    this.man = man;
  }
  public String toJSON(){
    String result="{";
    if (man != null) {
      result += "name:";
      if (man.name == null){
        result += "undefined"
      } else {
        result += "'" + StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_ECMASCRIPT.translate(man.name) +"'";
      }
      result += ",wife:";
      if (man.wife == null) {
         result += "undefined";
      } else {
         ...
      }
    }
    result += "}";
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: "About the creation of the JSON" that is the point of this question.

Comment: Do you miss something?

Comment: I don't think `About the creation of the JSON i suggest to use the "adapter-pattern", this means a lot of hand-written-code.` is enough of an answer to the heart of the question. I don't have any circular dependencies in my object structure and it is perfectly possible for me to create a normal JSON string with all the extra " and \ included. I will try to expand my question with examples to better illustrate my point...

Comment: You mean *you have no circular dependencies **yet***! What if someone add a circular dependency? A `OutOfMemoryError` kills your server and you will join the hall-of-fame.

Comment: Ok, that may be true, but don't Jackson handle such circular dependencies in its serialization from Java to JSON string?

Comment: I am confused, you say the creation of the JSON points to the heart of the question and for clearance you post already created JSON. But let me edit my answer for a concrete example how such a adapter could look like.

Comment: No, jackson is for parsing only. You would never ever find a opposite of jackson.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `No, jackson is for parsing only.` I use the following code to serialize from Java to JSON string right now `String jsonString = jacksonMapper.writeValueAsString(myBigJavaObjectWithMapsAndLists);`. This results in this kind of string: `'[{\"propertyA\":\"valueA\"}, {\"propertyB\":\"valueB\"}]'`

Comment: **I am shocked!** I advise against the jackson-serialization! You must set annotations to the getter if you need them or not (it breaks the DRY, SRP, OCP and OAOO Design-Principles).

Comment: But Jackson serialization is the default method for @RestControllers in spring mvc. There is nothing wrong with it...